# Ruby on Rails stylesheet_link_tag undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I changed my rails environment to production from development and im getting this error now.

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass <%= stylesheet_link_tag "LogIn", media: "all" %>

**config/internalizers/assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( LogIn.scss )
```

Does this have something to do with the asset pipeline not find the right file when its changed to production?

**production.log**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

Comment: replace `.scss` with `.css` on `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( LogIn.css )` and you need to have `gem 'sass-rails'` bundled on your gemfile

Comment: @sa77 still getting the same error I changed `.scss` to `.css` and I had the `'sass- rails' gem` installed.